# How to write unit test case for below TS function using jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angular7

I am trying to write unit testing for the below function (comparevalues). But I could not mock the data to cover the branch.
TS :

```
  public sortChange(sort: SortDescriptor[]): void {
    this.sort = sort;
    this.SelectedData.sort(this.compareValues(this.sort[0].field, this.sort[0].dir));
}

public compareValues(key: any, order: any) {
  return function(a, b) {
      if (!a.hasOwnProperty(key) || !b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          // property doesn't exist on either object
          return 0;
      }

      const varA = (typeof a[key] === 'string') ?
          a[key].toUpperCase() : a[key];
      const varB = (typeof b[key] === 'string') ?
          b[key].toUpperCase() : b[key];

      let comparison = 0;
      if (varA > varB) {
          comparison = 1;
      } else if (varA < varB) {
          comparison = -1;
      }
      return (
          (order === 'desc') ? (comparison * -1) : comparison
      );
  };
}
```

kindly help me to write unit test case for the **'if', 'else'** condition in "comparevalues" function

Answer (score 0):

In order to cover the `if` and `else` you need to mock the values from `this.SelectedData` together with the `key` from the function.

I assume that this is a component, so you could do like this to mock the `this.SelectedData`:

```
// add a spy for the property returning a xyz
const spy = spyOnProperty(component, 'SelectedData').and.returnValue([{ xyz: 23 }, { xyz: 44 }]);

// call the sortChange with the options looking for the key test that doesn't exist
component.sortChange([{ field: 'test', dir: 'asc' }])
```

To test the return of the function we need to mock it:

```
const spyFn = spyOn(component, 'compareValues').and.callThrough();

expect(spyFn.calls.first().returnValue).toEqual(0)
```

Full example:

```
// add a spy for the property returning a xyz
const spy = spyOnProperty(component, 'SelectedData').and.returnValue([{ xyz: 23 }, { xyz: 44 }]);
const spyFn = spyOn(component, 'compareValues').and.callThrough();

// call the sortChange with the options looking for the key test that doesn't exist
component.sortChange([{ field: 'test', dir: 'asc' }])

expect(spyFn.calls.first().returnValue).toEqual(0)
```

Then to test the other branches you can just take this example and apply properly according to the condition in the `if` and `else`s

Comment: I have tried the above solution. But I got this error. "Error: Property SelectedData does not have access type get."

Comment: Can you give more info about the SelectedData?

Comment: component.SelectedData = [{
      materialCode: 'mat-01',
      materialDesc: 'material desc',
      uomId: 2,
      uomDesc: 'uom-desc',
      materialQty: '10',
      expDeliveryQty: '1',
      exDeliveryDate: '15-03-2012',
   isMatSelected: true,
    },
 {
      materialCode: 'mat-02',
      materialDesc: 'material dasdesc',
      uomId: 1,
      uomDesc: 'uom-asd',
      materialQty: '10',
      expDeliveryQty: '11',
      expDeliveryDate: '15-03-2012',
      isMatSelected: true,
    }];

Comment: what if you try to change the variable directly before calling the function instead of mocking it like: `component.SelectedData = [{ xyz: 23 }, { xyz: 44 }]` or if is private `component['SelectedData'] = [{ xyz: 23 }, { xyz: 44 }]`?